# Groovy spock test case cant find autowired beans

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, groovy, spock

I have following structure of package and classes:
package com.abc.xyz.main.flow has two classes:

```
 ProcessA.java
 ProcessB.java
```

Now ProcessB is as:

```
     public class ProcessB{
     
     @Autowired
     ServiceX serviceX;
     @Autowired
     ServiceY serviceY;
     
}
```

package of ServiceX is: com.abc.xyz.main.adm.service
package of ServiceY is: com.abc.xyz.main.cmn.service

```
 I am writing groovy test case of ProcessA.java
 
package com.abc.xyz.main.flow


@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ProcessASpec extends Specification {
  //mocking code for ProcessA class
}
```

when run it gives error:
Field serviceX in com.abc.xyz.main.flow.ProcessB required a bean of type ServiceX

how to resolve

Comment: Could you show the TestConfig.class?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your Class test :

```
@TestConfiguration
   static class ConfigurationClass{
  
        @Bean
        public ServiceX serviceX() {
            return new ServiceX();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This means for all the fields it will complain about from other class(as I am writing test for ProcessA) ProcessB , I will have to implement those in my test class. Though this also worked for me and dint give any error: IN my test class declared these as 
      SpringBean
    ServiceX serviceX=Mock();  @SpringBean
    ServiceY serviceY=Mock().  But I just wanted to know that if there is any other way such that I dont need to mock these as these dont belong to my class ProcessA